# How to use ES6 to identify objects sharing one or more property values in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, javascript-objects

I have an array of objects to display:

```
const items = [
{
  id: 584,
  title: "spaceships",
  tags: ["space"],
},
{
  id: 372,
  title: "children's space",
  tags: ["children", "space"],
},
{
  id: 546,
  title: "teddy bears at the beach",
  tags: ["teddy bears", "beach"],
},
{
  id: 549,
  title: "children's toys",
  tags: ["children", "toys"],
}]
```

When I am displaying an individual item, I also want to show other items sharing the same tags, i.e. if the item is 372, I want to show 546 and 549 as related items. I can do it using loops, but how do I do it with ES6? This is what I have so far, but it's returning an empty array:

```js
const items = [{
    id: 584,
    title: "spaceships",
    tags: ["space"],
  },
  {
    id: 372,
    title: "children's space",
    tags: ["children", "space"],
  },
  {
    id: 546,
    title: "teddy bears at the beach",
    tags: ["teddy bears", "beach"],
  },
  {
    id: 549,
    title: "children's toys",
    tags: ["children", "toys"],
  }
];

const tags = ["children", "space"]

const relatedItems = items.filter((item) => {
  return item.tags.some((n) => tags.includes(n))
});

console.log(relatedItems);
```

Comment: Once you remove the syntax errors from the poorly named identifier for the variable, the code works. Rename `327 Tags` to `tags` and it works fine.

Comment: NB: for a one-liner you can remove the `{ }` and `return`:

`const relatedItems = items.filter(item => item.tags.some(n => tags.includes(n)));`

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, the first character of JavaScript variables must be a letter or an underscore, maybe that is why you are getting an empty array. You also have a space in the `327 Tags` variable.

With the array variable renamed to a working one, your code should return an array consisting of items whose tags include at least **one** occurrence from the 372Tags array. So in this case

```
[{
  id: 584,
  tags: ["space"],
  title: "spaceships"
}, {
  id: 372,
  tags: ["children", "space"],
  title: "children's space"
}, {
  id: 549,
  tags: ["children", "toys"],
  title: "children's toys"
}]
```

If you want the get the objects whose tags include **all** values from 372Tags, then you should use [every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every):

```
const relatedItems = items.filter((item) => {
  return tags.every((t) => item.tags.includes(t));
});
```

Which returns

```
[{
  id: 372,
  tags: ["children", "space"],
  title: "children's space"
}]
```